# Jquery check if there are some text in dynamically generated iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a script where when a user clicks the search button, the script will create an iframe with a specific address.
what I want, when the iframe is successfully opened, then the script will detect whether there is one keyword contained in the iframe.

If a keyword is found, an alert will come out stating the results related to that keyword

following the Jquery code that I have created:

```
$('#search').click(function(sp){
    sp.preventDefault();
    var nob= $('#noB').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var pin = $('#pin').val();
    if(nob==='' || year ==='' || pin===''){
        alert('All field Required');
        return false;
    }
    $('#SearchResult').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="https://dashboard.mysearchform.com/index.php?menu=result&office=0c4af0608cc742879b9960fe13e5764f&noB='+nob+'&year='+year+'&pin='+pin+'" style="width:105%;height:500px;margin-top:-60px;margin-left:-1%;"></iframe>');

    if($('iframe').contents().find("#iframe a:contains('Failure')").length()){
        alert('Data Not Found');
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the iFrame required? Could you simply perform an AJAX call and read the resulting HTML? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When you load an iFrame element, you may want to wait until the contents of the frame are `ready`. You can do this with `.ready()`. This way you know the content is loaded and ready.

Also you may want to capture the Body element and search this for your link. Remember that `:contains()` psuedo selector is Case Sensative. So a search for `"Failure"` will not find `"failure"`. If you're unsure which it might be, you may want to iterate each A element and search the text node with Regular Expressions.

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').click(function(sp) {
    sp.preventDefault();
    var nob = $('#noB').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var pin = $('#pin').val();
    if (nob === '' || year === '' || pin === '') {
      alert('All field Required');
      return false;
    }
    var fr = $("<iframe>", {
      id: "myFrame",
      src: "https://dashboard.mysearchform.com/index.php?menu=result&office=0c4af0608cc742879b9960fe13e5764f&noB=" + nob + "&year=" + year + "&pin=" + pin
    }).css({
      width: "105%",
      height: "500px;",
      marginTop: "-60px",
      marginLeft: "-1%"
    });

    fr.ready(function() {
      var ibody = fr.contents().find("body");
      var fail = ibody.find("a:contains('Failure')");
      console.log(fail.length);
      if (fail.length > 0) {
        alert('Data Not Found');
      }
    });

    $("#searchResults").html(fr);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li label {
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><label>noB:</label> <input type="text" id="noB"></li>
    <li><label>Year:</label> <input type="text" id="year"></li>
    <li><label>PIN:</label> <input type="text" id="PIN"></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="searchResults">
</div>
```

The URL does not appear to be valid or it cannot be loaded. But you can see how it would work.

As I mentioned in the comments, you could also perform a GET request via AJAX and just review the resulting HTML behind the scenes.

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search').click(function(sp) {
    sp.preventDefault();
    var n = $('#noB').val();
    var y = $('#year').val();
    var p = $('#pin').val();
    if (n === '' || y === '' || p === '') {
      alert('All field Required');
      return false;
    }
    $.get("https://dashboard.mysearchform.com/index.php", {
        menu: "result",
        office: "0c4af0608cc742879b9960fe13e5764f",
        noB: n,
        year: y,
        pin: p
      },
      function(results) {
        var fail = $(results).find("a:contains('Failure')");
        if (fail.length > 0) {
          alert('Data Not Found');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li label {
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><label>noB:</label> <input type="text" id="noB"></li>
    <li><label>Year:</label> <input type="text" id="year"></li>
    <li><label>PIN:</label> <input type="text" id="pin"></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="searchResults">
</div>
```

Hope that helps.